# switching jpanels as a jframe contentpane while running

Tags: java, swing

my program create a jframe > set the content pane to a jpanel > use repaint() one or more time > set the content pane to another jpanel > use some repaint() again > etc...
(note: for reasons i have to create the jframe then add the jpanel later)

but only calling `setContentPane(newjpanel)` doesnt allow me to use repaint() afterward and the only thing that i know will unlock it is resizing the window manually

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyJFrame() {
        // default panel for visual feedback
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        pan.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.setContentPane(pan);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // TODO
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        // other unrelated configuration stuff
        // ...

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void switchPanel(JPanel pan) {
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        // pan.setVisible(true); doesnt work
        // pan.revalidate(); neither
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyJFrame frame = new MyJFrame();

        //...
        JPanel mypan = new MyJPanel();
        // there i have an IO operation to get an image, without this delay this code work just fine
        // so i put this thread.sleep to simulate this delay
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        frame.switchPanel(mypan);

        while (true) {
            // this repaint wont work unless i change the window size
            mypan.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Point pos = new Point(0, 0);

        public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // i made the square move for visual feedback
            pos.x += 1;
            g.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 10, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

this code should show a square going in direction of +x

instead it wont until the window is resized

another option i know is setting visibility of the jframe to false changing the pane then setting it to true but it is really visualy unpleasant

so my question is, how could i make it possible to add/remove jpanels at run time? (adding code in switchPanel, adding container, really anything)

(2nd note: i would like to if possible REALLY add/remove jpanels at run time, im aware of using for example a card layout and turning off and on panels visibility in it but in cant do that there)

Comment: Generally in Swing, you create all of the JPanels in the beginning, then show or hide specific  JPanels with a CardLayout or a TabbedPane.  If you don't want to use Swing correctly, then you're on your own.

Comment: *im aware of using for example a card layout* - and that is what you should be using. Also you should not be using Thread.sleep(). For animation you should use a Swing Timer.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc look, this is getting a bit rude, its not because im far from conventions that i'm not allowed to ask, you may not like me from my last question but im really trying my best. thing is, i have a project to make, i may not have chosen the right way to achieve it but now im it and on some point i would love to get help but im not forcing anyone. thanks for your understanding

Comment: @camickr thanks, im aware for Thread.sleep, this is mostly test code to get my render engine working before going further. about the card layout, i know but doing it this way would require to refactor a lot, without getting alot of benefit from it, if i ever have to use swing the right way in another project i will, but right now, it would help me more to find an answer to precisely what im asking '^^, thanks for your understanding

Comment: *it would help me more to find an answer to precisely what im asking*  We need to better understand your requirement. It makes no sense to create a panel and then replace it immediately in the constructor of your class. Post a proper [mre] with every question. So the "MRE" should have a frame with a panel and a JButton that you press to replace the content pane. This will better represent your application. The while true logic does nothing  and is not required for an "MRE"

Comment: @camickr my mistakes, i updated the question to have an mre

Comment: I don't see a button anywhere. You already stated *for reasons i have to create the jframe then add the jpanel later* - so the point of the MRE is to simply replicate the problem you are attempting to solve. So this would mean initially displaying the frame with a default panel. And then have some kind of user interaction to replace the default panel with another panel. The easiest way to replicate this is to add a JButton with an ActionListener to replace the panel.

Comment: Nobody understands your question.  Why do you need two drawing panels?  Why do you need to switch from one drawing panel to another?  JPanels are double-buffered.  You can create BufferedImages in the background and paint different images on the one and only drawing JPanel.

Comment: @camickr i mean, i updated the code to be runnable and behave exactly like my program, it create the jframe, it set the content pane to the custom jpanel which is suposed to draw a square sliding to the right on repaint() but it doesnt until you resize the window, which is the exact problem that i encountered :/

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc im just stuck because i thought it would be trivial to do so, so i made my render engine to behave accordingly but now it appear it isnt trivial and either i find a fix or i refactor the whole thing and it will take time i would love to use to reach my goals instead. nontheless, i will always be interested in how fixing this, even if i refactor my code to use swing in a more standard way. a more technical reason would be that i have to add the jpanel after making the window visible because the jframe is created before the jpanel is created and i cant change it easily

Comment: Maybe this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676512/add-rectangle-to-a-jframe-in-a-different-class/64682646#64682646) will be of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When components are created they have a size of 0, so there is nothing to paint.

When you dynamically add a component to a visible frame, the you need to `revalidate()` the parent container you add the component to. This will invoke the layout manager on the parent container and the child components will be given a size/location.

Normally this would mean you `revalidate()` the `JPanel` you add the component to. However, in this case, since you are replacing the content pane, the easiest way to do that is to `revalidate()` the frame:

```
public void switchPanel(JPanel pan) {
    this.setContentPane(pan);
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: that indeed fix the problem for the mre. (my main program still doesnt work but i guess at this point for whats different between both its either a very dumb error in my code or some kind of black magic :/) anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, that is the first step - understanding the basic problem. The point of the MRE is to simplify the problem to isolate the cause. Then as you say it is a matter of seeing what is different between the real application and the MRE. I would suggest the problem is that the Thread.sleep() is being executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which is causing a problem.  That is why I stated you should be using a Swing Timer. In this MRE the code is NOT executing on the EDT. In your real example it probably executes as a result of a button click in which case the code does run on the EDT.

Comment: well, in my code it literaly execute around the same place as in the mre but the jpanel instantiation and call to switchpanel are made in a constructor of another object. is it possible that a bit of code change thread without explicitly calling any function related to threads? (or thread.sleep)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing, so I can't offer further advice. If you are swapping the panel without user interaction, then your code is completely wrong. There is no reason to set a default content panel and then swap it. The only reason to do the swap is the frame is visible with the original content pane and then the user initiates the swapping of the panel. You need to read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). All Swing components should be created on the EDT. Using Thread.sleep() on the EDT is wrong.

Comment: i mean, i have reasons to do so, it would just take an eternity to explain it and debate on it. about thread.sleep, i was only using it for debugging (i dont think there's any code running in the EDT so far?). anyway thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

here's a dirty fix that i found (work both for the mre and my main code)

```
public void switchPanel(JPanel pan) {
        this.setContentPane(pan);
        Dimension dim = this.getSize();
        int y = dim.height;
        int x = dim.width;
        this.setSize(x+1,y);
        this.setSize(x, y);
    }
```

tho it seem to be the equivalent of shutting down your pc to close a window, so not very appropriate.

Comment: *i dont think there's any code running in the EDT so far?* - and that is a problem. **All Swing components should be created and updated on the EDT.** If you don't fix the underlying design problem then you are asking for more troubles as you develop the application. A hack like this should not be used.